# Anychart support of grouped_tooltip without Anychartstock

Tags: xml, tooltip, apex, anychart

Anyone knows if anychart (not anychartstock) is able to use grouped tooltips? I cannot use anychartstock because I am unsing this product trough Apex 5.

This I got from the documentation of anychartstock but when trying to use it in the regular anychart line with several series I am getting nowhere.

```
          <grouped_tooltip>
            <labels>
              <format><![CDATA[Custom Text ({%Value}{numDecimals:2})]]></format> 
            </labels> 
          </grouped_tooltip>
```

Or in case you can do something similar without using anychartstock?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AnyChart 6.x version doesn't allow to use grouped tooltips, this feature is supported since 7.7.0 version, so you need to upgrade to 7.7.0 or higher to achieve this functionality:
http://docs.anychart.com/latest/Common_Settings/Tooltip#union

Comment: Hello, as a follow up question, how do you know which version of Anychart is installed? Is it possible to upgrade only Anychart for Apex?

Comment: APEX includes only version 6.x, versions 7.x are not directly compatible at the moment, you can't just upgrade and go, you'll have to create your own charting module with the new version. Probably at some point APEX will add the support of v 7, but we can't tell anything specific about that.